# Authentication with Openshift API running on IBM cloud failed with 401 unauthorized error

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, ibm-cloud, openid

I'm trying to build some application to manage my OpenShift cluster on IBM cloud and the first step is to authenticate against both IBM cloud and the OpenShift cluster.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-cs_api_install#kube_api

I followed the steps describe in the above link, and successfully obtained all the tokens including 'access_token', 'id_token' and 'refresh_token'. Among them the 'id_token' is supposed to be used to authenticate against the OpenShift API.

With the access_token I can visit IBM cloud API successfully, like obtaining account, cluster information.

However, when I use the id_token to call OpenShift API, it failed with the following error. It happened even for the '/version' api, which can be accessed without providing a bearer token.

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401
}
```

I can verify that my account have correct service roles assigned as described [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-access_reference#iam_issuer_users), and I can see corresponding roles with 'ibm' prefix assigned in OpenShift web portal as well.

Can anyone please verify that the instructions in the first link above is still valid or have any clue about what might have been wrong?

[Update]
To help troubleshooting, I paste a sample of tokens here, this is what I get for the step3 in the 'Working with your cluster by using the Kubernetes API' section in the link, it is a bit lengthy:

```
{
"access_token": "eyJraWQiOiIyMDIxMDIxOTE4MzUiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.Rm3F0UKz9Aq3-1xXMmkFi0UkENIvQUkRo6qhtWaG3LKBH5HHsZbAQeJUhKqXYbI643nj2ssDP2U50BVv-6zbpfmyVncP5Z5Dmi620mi2QesduRQaH1XlC-l7KuF3uT0hJ_9FSD-0Wqi5ph0pkKxHJ-BmLkHC-4F0NByiUtwIpwyTpthuzwC251XZsQ9Ya8gzCxHB9DFb3tzOF3cupVVZmc2mMJbv4JuTSnP00H5rOT4yIzeI0Lqm6LhDpMRJ4P8glmIxmU6fag42P94pFNf3jEzIZGl49NINiWXlKbAleij3vSouobtYvrBmxWQF4KpuwKPEI-bMf1zpsHPYBHWidg",
"id_token": "eyJraWQiOiIyMDIxMDIxOTE4MzUiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.Y42KUJRGgZA9OV164GAKSF0W5rRNGf3x32YXrAo5UvKhpOK0k4r_hwZU5BZhI2y3t-UqM7lNOIxexpft2Zmc9ApQ6BlVN-iN1jcfBzxmrUPMObpc1-vDrAc9Sq84J8nYzy1Rk32ydFHeb3V2iDhJn14_NOnXwhuz9EFkSg0uUZHugTAPx5A-VcdrehceX0yOqAOfX5EzTtmHoI8-JQbfNt8pyBSJs8Eoag7_mtfNgx13bP_-M8W7tltCSHhPEO46gUurPFkvasHggConPQ_oBw3ANAvY8tDfivrGmdiR2Q-uc4SnFAjOgC77YskDLskBcOeehhBvxwDkyufztzqM6w",
"refresh_token": "OKDsw87zCujUXCmb4LZ3-DFQN7lUa0ejdqau_fL3Voms7M7DaKYgO07gZW29VQbcwdGc3z8jrQjjf_4gOutKyRCZ6LyEiSEKTZQ6Kovwqji02Puxu3fzIFB9f8-a1hMlkTtP4u32_FTCmOZA6ARvzxEyRX36CtQEzSVz-zVMsvPxdgyztUEWPTtvbr7aPn4eq209OzTGzTyPCBFR-N0gVp2tKLbIrGmyi_vgC-6xLRvR2nWGJsUwaaBjXwvICeCBY3qRJ90VyP1krBSHa72f1XJWpvLnBWHN8qo1dfPknHvknlEZ3kMUA87KZkynkgiVifhRq90oNAKYHhKJ4XRs2tyz05zW5a8qEhgoIVsslUzDLLNU1btRF_3g587dKckPzEav3BgQlCik4im8gIC74HFGZOz4P7z9QKLJHQY7ElDillH8pLRjW8Dx0yZvn8Yo5rSqJSj0zUmJxNZMUNEpF_DTQhHCePNOWu1_1q4o5cIb_Mv-mGMMVwrVUsJYUyaeV9O5cWl58eWlHQxS3SbuAjsBrzfSdcrIyFe5aQViyL_sL1-o54xFrMJPC3prPD25TS4vUOwAy7tc9r1AGZG00YUGaxPwzKcOWBI4DqksIiEKPOtcm3k0y24TuwRPa0AK-9jfYAzkx3rciBYGKbq1WOFjX-p6LH67ayxVUJcQcjSMe-35LZnsHQtc0VOxNHjJKdJiHsKOYEDY1Nz0k4zGZr1EZ6j7w4tLpBXP9ThC8hReiihWDmld9lzFdLwKZPF7jl4u03a2WQZ6j-wMHvLtOBcLDiKwEaeWaGp8v_YS3j4iGqkcAytf7z_-toD1O3ZHtIUlbe6H64IAVPKadN1Y1SD49Ouk1fk8xDFr7HQ4RuDTLfZnLGzC4vvzysCmJEX837Wjf2f9WdirEaKxoSlDDJKilt--20Ota-5CTimD8u0SttC6CD1Glj8bbAS8ddCAfVirDJty7FW3eyALvAHifKqzRa1kBDPHb305q91oSWYdzBKIlTinN9BAXDc3ZccVkWM6Y3VgUzh2iQwM0lKadts7OMwqhLDk7rukAXHRUpKxy-85rUf-a0oz41s69PXdQteoh559vEb0uyrq0kOnI1RnuJ7MaEGDC25Kfezumo0snwYRmQhXMPMeKkxBKxs9ZydKxxcp1qtLwFyHA6MhZuXRpZM9Qse9mqovNdHHOhAQIZu3J7HJusuVdg3SJhZkTH__gXpCc2hBeOpR0rPc6qZm7z2nU5pJQ2XgzH2TUm6psA",
"ims_user_id": 8873576,
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600,
"expiration": 1614259586,
"refresh_token_expiration": 1616847976,
"scope": "ibm openid containers-kubernetes"
```

}

In addition, the following approach works but the token is obtained through the OpenShift web console, and thus cannot be obtained programmatically(at least I don't see how),

```
"Authorization: Bearer sha256~6V_OvZ5OoV8vnHF33Es5qsloAY-iXkLQ8dfl_Nsyn94"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not and should not send the ID-Token to get access to APIs, its only meant to be used by the client who did the initial authentication. It also typically have a very short lifetime (like 5 minutes in some implementation).

The only purpose of the ID-token is basically o create the local user session.

On the page you refer to it says at the end:

> ID token: Every IAM ID token that is issued via the CLI expires after
> one hour. When the ID token expires, the refresh token is sent to the
> token provider to refresh the ID token. Your authentication is
> refreshed, and you can continue to run commands against your cluster.

It sounds like they mean the access token. In openID connect you don't renew your ID-token (what I am aware of)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask are you referring to ID-Token in OpenID in general or the one in this specific case? Because in this [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-cs_api_install#kube_api), it is clearly stated to use 'Authorization: bearer <id_token>' for authentication.

Comment: I don't know about this specific case, but my answer is in the general sense.

Comment: Not sure if you are interested but [here](https://medium.com/@martin.smolny/ibm-cloud-identity-and-access-management-tokens-in-details-49eac14d5298) is an article explaining the purpose of different kinds of tokens on IBM cloud, though it does not address my issue. BTW, I have tried to use either 'access_token' or 'refresh_token' obtained instead of the 'id_token', neither of it worked.

Comment: You get an error of Unauthorized, not unauthenticated, so that I would suspect that the token was accepted, but then in the second step you look at if the user roles/claims, then it failed. You do establish the auhtorization after authentication.

Comment: I tend to agree with you about this. But in fact I have tried to use a random string instead of any actual token, it reported the same unauthorized error, so I would doubt there are any kind of authentication here.

Comment: perhaps it returns the same error either case, you can't see any logs on the receiving end?

Comment: perhaps try to paste in a sample access token in the question? does the kid exist in the JWKS endpoint?

Comment: Sure, updated information in the OP. About the receiving side, it is on IBM cloud thus I do not have access to its internal logs.

Comment: it looks like the access and id tokens are swapped? your ID token contains the "aud": "kube", claim, that is a claim typical for the access token to contain :-) But I have never used IBM cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Have been busy in the past few days, I will share how I solved this problem here. In fact it didn't address the original issue, but is another way to achieve the goal.

So it turned out that there was [another doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-access_cluster#access_api_key) regarding how the access token can be obtained(Yes, as mentioned by @Tore Nestenius it should be an access token instead of an id token). The token described here is actually the same as what one would get through the Openshift web console. And basically it has nothing to do with the previous link I shared in the question.